# VirtualQuery gives illegal result. Is it a bug?

Tags: virtualquery

My code:

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminf;
::VirtualQuery(box.pBits, &meminf, sizeof(meminf));
```

The results:

```
   meminf:
    BaseAddress          0x40001000    void *
    AllocationBase       0x00000000    void *
    AllocationProtect    0x00000000    unsigned long
    RegionSize           0x0de0f000    unsigned long
    State                0x00010000    unsigned long
    Protect              0x00000001    unsigned long
    Type                 0x00000000    unsigned long
```

Notes:

(1) AllocationBase is NULL while BaseAddress is not NULL
(2) AllocationProtect is 0 (not a protection value)

Is it a bug of VirtualQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Passing a kernel-mode pointer to this function can result in no information being returned.
Check the return value.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. The [documentation of `VirtualQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366902%28VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> The return value is the actual number of bytes returned in the information buffer.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError. Possible error values include ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

Check the function result to be equal to `sizeof(meminf)` before using the data in the structure, or initialize the structure with values that will make the code that follows do the right thing. If the function returned 0 no data was copied to the structure, so it will still contain whatever data was previously in it. Without initialization this will be random bytes on the stack.